Why can my body be used as a ground in this situation?
I have a USB sound card (a CM108 clone) that picks up digital noise from the motherboard when recording audio from the microphone. I grounded the computer with an individual ground to reduce the noise, it reduces the noise a bit but there is still noise being recorded.
I’ve read in various places that digital and analog grounds should not be shared. That was common practice in the past, but today it seems less of a concern. In modern equipment, digital and analog grounds are often combined. Despite this, when I touch the soundcard’s USB connector shield, the digital noise disappears entirely.
My theory is that my body doesn’t act as a ground, but rather functions as a large antenna, emitting the noise into the air. Am I correct, or is there another explanation? How can I replace my body by an object? Can I use something such as a piece of metal or a container of water?

It sounds like your computer doesn't have an earth/ground connection at the wall-plug or, maybe you are using a laptop on a charger or... maybe you should fill in the details. The first trick is to figure out why it's noisy.

The antenna model is more correct. Infact the human body has a few pfs of capacitance when objects are near in a room and acts as an antenna. You can pick up 60Hz well. If you have an oscilloscope, don't touch anything else and touch the probe, in most cases the antenna effect will show on the scope.

Interesting. I also hypothesize that (maybe) the noise is energy circulating in the system and when I touch it I become part of the circuit itself and consume a bit of this total "noise" or energy.
